# How did you go about studying for your LPI certification?

Tags: untagged

http://www.lpi.org/eng

Additionally, how much does each test cost?

Answer (score 6):

I used these books:

- [LPIC Exam Cram](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0789731274)
- [LPI Linux Certification in a Nutshell](http://www.oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005283/)

and the following website:

- [IBM's dev works website](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/lpi/101.html?S_TACT=105AGX03&S_CMP=TILE)

Remember to try all the examples.  You can't rote memorize this stuff, you have to understand it.

From ([www.lpi.org/eng/certification/faq/procedure_for_taking_exams](http://www.lpi.org/eng/certification/faq/procedure_for_taking_exams))
"Depending on where you take LPI exams, the cost will usually be the equivalent of $160 US dollars."

Remember the re-take policy:

- Anyone who takes an LPI exam once must wait one week before re-taking.
- Anyone who takes an LPI exam a second (and subsequent) time must wait 90 days before re-taking.
- Anyone who passes an LPI exam may not retake that exam for at least two years.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing beats experience. LPIC1 is designed for people with a couple of years experience with Linux. If you have that, then you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Be prepared to learn a lot of little factoids by heart. Get yourself a [book](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596005283/) (I used that one when I did LPIC1 back in 2007), and be sure to check out the sample questions in there. They give a pretty good image of what awaits you.

Answer (score 0):

I think the cost for taking LPIC exams varies by territory.

Experiences of LPIC seem to vary wildly, personally I found that the first couple of LPIC examinations weren't challenging; you need to be able to remember a *lot* of mostly useless factoids which you'll rarely deploy from your administration arsenal in a professional capacity.

Moving onto LPIC-2 and LPIC-3 presents more challenges.

Would I say you need two years experience to pass the first one?  Probably not. Any talented amateur who has actually used Linux on a daily basis for a few months can probably hack it, with a small amount of study :)  The LPIC-2 and LPIC-3 require some **real** CLI experience and "advanced" knowledge.

Picking up LDAP early will also serve you well, most folks find it a bit of a 'head fsck' and not entirely intuitive yet it forms the foundation for LPIC-3 and, indeed, administration of **any** large scale environment with more than 40-50 servers, clients and users.